# Outlook 365 "clean up" feature not removing duplicate emails with attachments

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an inbox that I've migrated a couple of times by exporting the contents to pst files, reimporting it, etc. In the process, I've run into a situation where the server sometimes still has a subset of the exported emails online, and I end up with duplicate emails when I resync.

When I imported the pst file, I selected the option not to import duplicates, which seemed to have no effect (or at least, when I reestablished the connection with the server, they were re-downloaded afterwards).

I tried using the "clean up files & subfolders" feature in Outlook, but it doesn't actually seem to do anything:

[image]

I tried removing all of the

I'm using Outlook version 2003 (Build 12624.20466) with a Microsoft 365 subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook clean up feature is not specifically for clearing duplicate emails.

> > or at least, when I reestablished the connection with the server, they were re-downloaded afterwards

Please import pst file with "not to import duplicates" option after complete synchronization.